# Replace a character by a line break

Tags: javascript, ajax, jmeter, notepad++

I have a ajax server response

```
{
    "applicationBankList": [
        {
            "id": "${addressId}",
            "accountNumber": "",
            "accountName": "",
            "paymentMethodCode": "DRDEB",
            "name": "BANKOFENGLAND",
            "yearsWithBank": "8",
            "bankSortCode": "100000",
            "monthsWithBank": "8",
            "branch": "HeadOffice",
            "sortCode": "10-00-00",
            "validationInformation": "",
            "validationStatus": ""
        }
    ],
    "applicationBillingAddress": {
        "defaultFlag": "Y"
    }
}
```

I need to make it much human readable by aligning them properly, i have huge set of responses its quite very hard to read them so i am looking for a solution which automatically formats for human readability 
is there any solution for this

Comment: Are you attempting to make it pretty for debugging or permanently? What's the server using for it's language PHP, C#, Perl?

Comment: i just want to make it pretty for debugging

Comment: If we are taking manually, either throw the response in [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or download the [JSTool plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/). If you want this to happen in the code, pass the string into here: ``JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonStr,undefined,'\t'));``

Comment: JSTool Saved my day thanks MR.Polywhirl. i am new to this so finding a bit hard to learn \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanting it pretty defeats the purpose of using json.  It's meant to be compact, adding spaces, line breaks, and indents, goes against the grain.

If you want to debug or check the structure of it: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: If you have access to the server and using php you can use JSON_PRETTY_PRINT as the second parameter to json_encode() for it to format it, but not recommended for production use.

Answer (score 0):

I think making it "human-readable" has to be done on the server-side. What you are getting is the server-response, the way it is sent. Do you have access to the server code that returns the response string?

Comment: Once when it reaches to me from server i just want to make it human readable just to debug it ,